# Recurrence Relationf or a Quaternary Sequence

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations

Find a recurrence relation for the number of quaternary (4base digits) sequences with no copy of $3000$ as a subsequence.

Workings:

First digit $0, 1, 2$ Proceed as normal:

$3a_{n-1}$

If first digit is $3$ next number can be can be $0, 1, 2$

$3a_{n-2}$

If 3, 0 then

$3a_{n-3}$

If 3, 0 , 0. There can't be another 0

$2a_{n-4}$

This gives:

$a_n = 3a_{n-1} + 3a_{n-2} + 3a_{n-3} + 2a_{n-4}$

I don't believe this is correct. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The set of quaternary sequences without the sub-sequence $3000$ can be parsed by following regular expression

$$\big(0^*(3|30|300)^*(1|2)\big)^*0^*(3|30|300)^*\tag{*1}$$

where $S^*$ stands for the [Kleene star](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene_star) for the 
set of strings $S$. Based on this regular expression, we can read off the corresponding OGF 
(ordinary generating function). The rules one need to know are:

1. Replace every letter (in this case, the digits $0, 1, 2, 3$ )by a variable $t$.
2. if $g_A(t)$, $g_B(t)$ are OGF for pattern $A$ and $B$, the OCF for

   - $AB$   - string concatenation of pattern $A$ followed by $B$ is $g_A(t)g_B(t)$
   - $A|B$  - disjoint union/alternate possibilities of two patterns is $g_A(t) + g_B(t)$
   - $A^*$  - Kleene star of $A$, i.e. repeat the pattern $A$ zero to arbitrary many times is $\frac{1}{1-g_A(t)}$.

Following these rules,

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
0^* &\leadsto& 1 + t + t^2 + \ldots = \frac{1}{1-t}\\
(3|30|300) &\leadsto& t + t^2 + t^3 = \color{red}{\frac{t-t^4}{1-t}}\\
(3|30|300)^* &\leadsto& \frac{1}{1- \color{red}{\frac{t-t^4}{1-t}}} = \frac{1-t}{1-2t+t^4}\\
0^*(3|30|300)^* &\leadsto& \left(\frac{1}{1-t}\right)\left(\frac{1-t}{1-2t+t^4}\right) = \color{green}{\frac{1}{1-2t+t^4}}\\
0^*(3|30|300)^*(1|2) &\leadsto& \left(\color{green}{\frac{1}{1-2t+t^4}}\right) 2t = \color{blue}{\frac{2t}{1-2t+t^4}}
\end{array}$$

Combine these, the OGF for $(*1)$ is given by

$$\text{OCF}_{3000}(t) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n t^n =
\left(\frac{1}{1 - \color{blue}{\frac{2t}{1-2t+t^4}}}\right)\left(\color{green}{\frac{1}{1-2t+t^4}}\right) = \frac{1}{1-4t+t^4}\tag{*2}$$

This implies the sequence $a_n$ satisfies a recurrence relation of the form:
$$a_n = \begin{cases} 
4a_{n-1} - a_{n-4}, &n > 0,\\
1, & n = 0,\\
0, & n < 0
\end{cases}
$$
One can then use this to determine the values of $a_n$ recursively.

$$(a_0,a_1,\ldots) = (1,4,16,64,255,1016,4048,16128,64257,256012,1020000,\ldots)$$

**Update**

About the question whether there is a simpler argument that give us the same answer.
For this particular problem, the answer is yes but there is a catch!

Given any sequence, we will call it admissible if it is quaternary and didn't contain the sub-sequence $3000$. It is clear:

1. Given any admissible sequence of length $n$, if one remove the leading digit, we get
   an admissible sequence of length $n-1$.
2. Conversely, given any admissible sequence of length $n-1$, if we prepend it with 
   a quaternary digit, we will get back an admissible sequence of length $n$ as long
   as the digit we add is not $3$ and the original sequence didn't begin with $000$.
3. Since the sub-sequence $000$ doesn't contain the digit $3$, prepend it or delete 
   it from the "head" of a sequence won't change its status of admissibility.
   This means there is a $1$-$1$ correspondence between admissible sequence of length $n-1$ with prefix $000$ and admissible sequence of length $n-4$.

Combine these, one obtain the same recurrence relation as before

$$a_n = 4 a_{n-1} - a_{n-4},\quad\text{ for } n > 4\tag{*3}$$

What is the catch? The catch is in step $3$.

When we analysis problem like this, it is easy to forget the $1$-$1$ correspondence
between the admissible sequence of length $n-1$ with a specific prefix of length $k$
and admissible sequence of length $n-1-k$ is not guaranteed.

If the prefix contains the leading digit, $(*3)$ can fail.
For example, if we replace the excluded sub-sequence $3000$ by $3030$, the OCF 
is no longer that in $(*2)$. Instead, it becomes

$$\begin{align}
\text{OCF}_{3030}(t)
&= \frac{1+t^2}{1-4t+t^2-4t^3+t^4}\\
&= 1+4t+16t^2+64t^3+255t^4+1016t^5+4049t^6+16136t^7+\cdots
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks for the help. But I have to imagine there was a simpler way to get the answer since this was a question I had on a test that was worth 3 points.